# Why can't I decrypt an mcrypt encrypted text with opnssl using blowfisch an PHP 7.x

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, mcrypt, blowfish

Why can't I decrypt an mcrypt encrypted text with openssl

I have encrypted information in the database and in apps on mobile devices.

So far, these have been encrypted and decrypted on a server with PHP 7.0 and mcrypt.
- The deprecated message is already displayed there.

There will be no mcrypt in the next PHP versions. So I tried to do that with openssl.
Although I also use blowfish with mode CFB at openssl, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#
# mcrypt on Server with PHP 7.0

/**
 * encrypt with Blowfish and mcrypt
 */
function mcrypt_encrypt($plaintext, $key)
{
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, '');
    $ivsize = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivsize, MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $crypttext = mcrypt_generic($td, $plaintext);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    return $iv . $crypttext;
}

/**
 * decrypt with Blowfish and mcrypt
 */
function mcrypt_decrypt($crypttext, $key)
{
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, '');
    $ivsize = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);
    $iv = substr($crypttext, 0, $ivsize);
    $crypttext = substr($crypttext, $ivsize);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $plaintext = mdecrypt_generic($td, $crypttext);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    return $plaintext;
}
```

This works on PHP 7.0:

```
$plaintext = 'Hello World';
$mcrypt_crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt($plaintext,'secret');
$mcrypt_plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt($mcrypt_crypttext,'secret');

# $plaintext == $mcrypt_plaintext;
```

The new funktions with OpenSSL:

```
#
# openssl on Server with PHP 7.2

/**
 * encrypt with Blowfish and openssl
 */
function openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $key)
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length('bf-cfb');
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $crypttext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'bf-cfb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return $iv . $crypttext;
}

/**
 * decrypt with Blowfish and openssl
 */
function openssl_decrypt($crypttext, $key)
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length('bf-cfb');
    $iv = substr($data, 0, $ivlen);
    $crypttext = substr($data, $ivlen);
    $plaintext = openssl_decrypt($crypttext, 'bf-cfb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return $plaintext;
}
```

This works also:

```
$openssl_crypttext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext,'secret');
$openssl_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($openssl_crypttext,'secret');

# $plaintext == $openssl_plaintext;
```

But this goes wrong - decrypting the mcrypt encrypted text:

```
$openssl_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($mcrypt_crypttext,'secret');

# $plaintext != $openssl_plaintext
```

Is there a way to decrypt mcrypted data with PHP7.2?

Comment: it must be somehow possible?
You can surely decrypt a blowfish encrypted string with another programming language, right?
So encrypt with PHP and decrypt with Java.
That must be the same on every system.?!